# Can I use grant_type="password" to obtain refresh_token to refresh access_token to access my API

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have created a service, without user interaction, to access my API. The Api needs to know the user. Therefore I need the resource-owner flow.

For accessing my Api I need an access_token with the correct scope "MyApiScope".
I can obtain an access_token with the resource-owner flow specifying scope="MyApiScope". But I won't get a refresh token in this way.

I can obtain a refresh_token with the resource-owner flow specifying scope="offline_access". But the access_tokens generated with this refresh token can't be used to access my Api because they do not contain the right scope, "offline_access" != "MyApiScope".

Is it just not possible in this scenario to use refresh tokens and should I therefore always use the username/password to obtain a new access_token?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Nothing prevent you from using both `offline_access` and `MyApiScope` scopes

Comment: How simple can it be! I added the scope and it worked! I just wasn't aware that you had to concatenate the scopes with spaces in between (url-encoded of course). `grant_type=password&username={USERNAME}&password={PASSWORD}&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}&scope=MyApiScope offline_access`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add all the required scopes separated by spaces.
`grant_type=password&username={USERNAME}&password={PASSWORD}&‌​client_id={CLIENT_ID‌​}&client_secret={CLI‌​ENT_SECRET}&scope=My‌​ApiScope offline_access`

Comment: you should URL-encode the spaces to "%20"; when pasted in a browser that will perhaps be done automatically but in general it isn't